# "Object Not Found" error in phpmyadmin

Tags: firefox, phpmyadmin

I installed xampp in window 7 . but whenever i tried to click home button in phpmyadmin .  the url turn weird and it doesn't redirect to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/main.php?token=b0ffa519161e4c2e54c230a2fe97107a
```

and redirect to the following instead .

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/://localhost/phpmyadmin/navigation.php?server=1&token=b0ffa519161e4c2e54c230a2fe97107a&db=&table=&lang=en-utf-8&collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
```

so it showed "Objects not found message" because that url isn't supposed to be . but it totally ok when i tried with Control + Click .  please help me to fix it . it only happened when i clicked four icons ,  Home , SQL , question mark and other SQL icon from left side of phpmyadmin  btw it totally fine in chrome browser (version 17.0.963.2)  but not ok in firefox (16.0.2)  and phpmyadmin version is 3.3.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only with a specific browser only as you stated out then you can clear your browsers cache and check..

Under Firefox main menu click on Tools->Clear Recent History and clear out Everything..

Comment: now you can try two more things..one, to check the url in Firefox Safe Mode and two, reinstall Firefox afresh without saving/using any previous profiles'..

Comment: just re-installed  Firefox

Comment: @RishiKalia: still i didn't solve it. can you help me?

Comment: @SELVA Is your problem same as OP ?